# Doctrine queryBuilder addSelect syntax

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm maintaining a Symfony 2.2 application, and I have to change some queries to fix a rounding problem. We use Doctrine ORM and queryBuilder to do the database stuff. Here's some sample code:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($alias);
$qb->join('t.store', 'store')
   ->addSelect('w')
   ->leftJoin('t.lines', 'l', 'WITH',
       $qb->expr()->andX(
         $qb->expr()->eq('l.rejected', 0)
       )
    )
    // WRONG  ->addSelect('SUM(l.price * l.amount * (1 + l.tax + l.retax)) AS total')
   ->leftJoin('t.warns','w')->groupBy('t')->addGroupBy('w')
   ->orderBy('t.id', 'DESC');
```

I have to change the commented line (starting with **// WRONG**) so it applies a couple of roundings to the taxes, so it should be:

```
->addSelect('SUM(l.price * l.amount) + 
             ROUND(l.price * l.amount * l.tax, 2) + 
             ROUND(l.price * l.amount * l.retax, 2) AS total')
```

When I run the app, it gives me a 500 internal server error. If I remove the 'ROUND' function, it works (but it doesn't do the correct roundings).

**EDIT**
As requested, here's the `doctrine` section of the config.yml file:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
        default:
            driver:   %database_driver%
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %database_name%
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    gedmo_tree:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTree 
                        is_bundle: false

                    gedmo_loggable:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoLoggable 
                        is_bundle: false
                dql:
                    numeric_functions:
                        round: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Round
```

What's wrong with it? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

`ROUND` function is not available out of the box. Remember, while there is a `ROUND` function in `SQL`, you are dealing here with `DQL`.

One way to overcome this is to install [`doctrine-extensions`](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) which provides many `DQL` functions, `ROUND` included. <strike>Alternatively, you can install a bundle [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle), which will take care of configuring those functions.</strike>

Hope this helps...

### UPDATE:

1. Install [`beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions). As the repo README states, it represents "A set of extensions to Doctrine 2 that add support for functions available in MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLite.". The comprehensive list of function quickly reveals there is `ROUND` included.
2. Register the function. There is really good [Symfony official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) on the topic. For example:

   ```
   # config/packages/doctrine.yaml
   doctrine:
       orm:
           # ...
           dql:
               numeric_functions:
                   round: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Round
   ```

Comment: I see that the app has 'gedmo doctrine-extensions' installed. Also, in `app/config/config.yml` I can see  2 gedmo mappings (gedmo_tree and gedmo_loggable) under the 'doctrine/orm' key. Could you please help me on what I need to add to support the 'ROUND' function in DQL? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake with copy paste of URL. It seems that `gedmo` does not have set of cross platform `DQL` function, but instead `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` does. I am updating the answer...

Comment: Hi! I just realized that the app also has the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle installed under 'vendor/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle'. I'll investigate a bit to see if I can find what I need. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. `gedmo` extensions are behavior-based extensions and not a function-based.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question (I'm new to Symfony): Do I need to run some command or do anything when I change the `config.yml` file?

Comment: Assuming that you are attempting to load `dev` environment, I don't think so, no. For `prod`, you would have to `cache:clear`. Do you get some error?

Comment: Yes, I get a 500 internal server error. I'll update when I find the reason.

Comment: Still not working... Shouldn't the function register line in config.yml have something like 'Beberlei'? I mean: `round: Beberlei\DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Round` or something like that?

Comment: Does not seem so, according to the [source code](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/Round.php). What is the actual error your are seeing? `HTTP 500 Internal error` 
 is `prod` saying something went upside down, but what does the `dev` say?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, we had a bank holiday and I didn't come to work. This is the error the app throws: `[2018-08-16 13:20:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 68: Error: Expected known function, got 'ROUND'" at /isp/www/docs/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.`. It seems that it's not loading the 'ROUND' function from the DoctrineExtensions...

Comment: weird...  can you please update your question with `doctrine` section of `config.yml`?